Which polynomials are bijective modulus any n?
This question has two parts. First, which polynomials are bijective in modular arithmetic with mod n? Second, which polynomials are bijective given any n?
So far I know that any linear function nx will not be bijective given any n because if the modulus is n then it will be equivalent to the 0 function. I also know that you can trivially add any constant to a bijective function to get another bijective function.
So far the only polynomials I have found that are bijective in any modulus are x+c and -x+c where c is any constant. Are there other polynomials with this property or are these all?
Edit: I have since posting this question learned that these bijection inducing polynomials are called permutation polynomials and if there were such a polynomial for every modulus, it would have to be a composition of Dickson polynomials (and x+c or -x+c.)

I think you want to look up Dickson polynomials (and then report back to us on what you find).

@GerryMyerson Thanks for the tip. Wikipedia says, "Fried (1970) proved that any integral polynomial that is a permutation polynomial for infinitely many prime fields is a composition of Dickson polynomials and linear polynomials (with rational coefficients)." So this narrows things down quite a bit. The only candidates remaining are compositions of Dickson polynomials (possibly multiplied by -1.)

Also since the constant in each polynomial can be changed that would change the way they are composed. Hmm...
